# Change Speed of a Css Slider on Hover

Tags: css, html, slider

Can anyone give me a solution as to how to slow down the speed of  my slides display for?

I follow the code from: http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/FastHoverSlideshow/

This has a `css` slider properties. I already tried to change the properties of `animation duration` like `0.8s > 5s` but there is an error in sliding with images. Please help me as fast as anyone can.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you hav to change all the `.hs-wrapper img:nth-child` speed also they are set to change after 0.1 sec

```
.hs-wrapper img{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: showMe 4s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -moz-animation: showMe 4s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -o-animation: showMe 4s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -ms-animation: showMe 4s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    animation: showMe 4s linear infinite 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;   
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(1){
    z-index: 9;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    z-index: 8;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    z-index: 7;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(4){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    z-index: 6;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(5){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    z-index: 5;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(6){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    z-index: 4;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(7){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3s;
    -ms-nimation-delay: 3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    z-index: 3;
}
.hs-wrapper img:nth-child(8){
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
    z-index: 2;
}
```